# Error while installing Python-saml package in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, single-sign-on, saml

I would like to use python-saml for sso integration with flask web app. while I am trying to install python-saml package using `pip install python-saml`, I am getting the below error message.

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\sekar>pip install python3-saml==1.9.0
Collecting python3-saml==1.9.0
  Using cached python3_saml-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting xmlsec>=0.6.0
  Using cached xmlsec-1.3.3.tar.gz (29 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
  Building wheel for xmlsec (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myvenv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sekar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\16\\pip-install-9x0le85b\\xmlsec\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sekar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\16\\pip-install-9x0le85b\\xmlsec\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\Temp\16\pip-wheel-39e4ydgb'
       cwd: C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\Temp\16\pip-install-9x0le85b\xmlsec\
  Complete output (5 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  error: HTTP Error 404: The specified blob does not exist.
  Retrieving "https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/hij3a6776pdv2007/artifacts/libxml2-2.9.4.win64.zip" to "build/extra\libxml2-2.9.4.win64.zip"
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
  Running setup.py clean for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
Installing collected packages: xmlsec, python3-saml
    Running setup.py install for xmlsec ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myvenv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sekar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\16\\pip-install-9x0le85b\\xmlsec\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sekar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\16\\pip-install-9x0le85b\\xmlsec\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\Temp\16\pip-record-l_q25m6k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myvenv\Include\xmlsec'
         cwd: C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\Temp\16\pip-install-9x0le85b\xmlsec\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    error: HTTP Error 404: The specified blob does not exist.
    Retrieving "https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/hij3a6776pdv2007/artifacts/libxml2-2.9.4.win64.zip" to "build/extra\libxml2-2.9.4.win64.zip"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myvenv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sekar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\16\\pip-install-9x0le85b\\xmlsec\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sekar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\16\\pip-install-9x0le85b\\xmlsec\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\Temp\16\pip-record-l_q25m6k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\sekar\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myvenv\Include\xmlsec' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried with `conda install python-saml`, same error also they stopped this package 2 years before. even I tried `python3-saml`

the core issue is in xmlsec package..

is there any conda channels or PYPI  provide this package?

Comment: VidyaSekar  specified url 'https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/hij3a6776pdv2007/artifacts/libxml2-2.9.4.win64.zip" to "build/extra\libxml2-2.9.4.win64.zip ' is not exist so that causes   'error: HTTP Error 404: The specified blob does not exist.'

Comment: It seems xmlsec causing the problem

Comment: yes even I am trying with 'pip install python-xmlsec-1.3.6.tar.gz'.. this package is also not installing

Comment: https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/issues/88
There are older issues with the same problem. It's a trial and error. You will have to install it manually. Try https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.5 though this is version 1.3.5. You require >=0.6.0 which would theoretically still pass the installation stage but snice major version was change there probably were some breaking changes. If it does not work look for a lesser version.

Comment: @TinNguyen, I tried with all version of xmlsec. even I downloaded the whl file and tried the installation. Nothing worked out

Comment: Paste your errors then. It will be different. Because if you installed python-xmlsec through the alternative methods it will not try to install it again when you install python3-saml since you are fulfilling the python-xmlsec requirement.

Comment: **Command :** pip install xmlsec-1.3.52.dev0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl **ERROR:** xmlsec-1.3.52.dev0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Are you following the proper procedure for using pip with Conda (see, for example https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

Comment: This seems to be fixed with `xmlsec==1.3.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Since version 1.3.7, prebuilt wheels of `xmlsec` for Windows are published on PyPI, so you shouldn't experience this issue anymore.

#### Original answer

I have rebuilt `xmlsec` windows wheels and uploaded them to the [releases page of my fork](https://github.com/hoefling/xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.6.post1). To install, first install `xmlsec` passing the additional PyPI index:

```
$ pip install xmlsec --extra-index-url=https://hoefling.io/pypi
```

The added index just proxies install request to Github releases.

Now install `python3-saml`:

```
$ pip install python3-saml
```

#### (Alternative) Selecting the dist manually

You can manually find the wheel matching your Python installation from the [releases page](https://github.com/hoefling/xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.6.post1) and install it using a direct link, e.g.

```
$ python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(*get_supported()[0], sep='-')"
cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
# the matching wheel is thus xmlsec-1.3.6.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
$ pip install https://github.com/hoefling/xmlsec/releases/download/1.3.6.post1/xmlsec-1.3.6.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

#### (Optional) Verify `xmlsec` works by invoking the tests

I have executed tests against all built wheels (check out [this job log on Appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/hoefling/python-xmlsec/builds/32450891)), but you can also run the tests locally to verify `xmlsec` installation is working:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec.git && cd python-xmlsec
$ pip install pytest
$ pytest tests/
```

Answer (score 1):

Never used python-saml here... However, while searching this error, I found these GitHub issues: [Issue 1](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/issues/30) and [Issue 2](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/issues/237)

Both of them talk about a problem with dm.xmlsec.binding.

Best,
Felipe

Comment: So there is no way to install xmlsec? or need to find any more dependencies?

Comment: Hi. So I do not have experience with this package; however, from what I read, you can try pip install dm.xmlsec.binding==1.3.1